# Zend Model with Join

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a NewsModel which extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract. the news-table consists of: newsid, title, text and creater. creater reffers to a userid of the user-table. User-table consists of userid and username.

Now i want to have the User in the NewsModel. At the moment

At the moment I do this in the model:

```
$select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
                        ->setIntegrityCheck(false);
        $select->join('muskelpilot_users',
        'muskelpilot_users.userid= muskelpilot_news.creater',
        'username');
        return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

Is there any other solution to solve this problem without a method?

Comment: so far I don't know any other methods to make joins using zf. I believe apart using some ORM  you would have to specify the joined table and join conditions no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify relationships in your Models, which allow you to do this:

```
$newsModel = new NewsModel();
$news = $newsModel->find(1); // find a row, returns an instance of Zend_Db_Table_Row
$user = $news->findDependentRowset('User'); // returns instance of Zend_Db_Table_Rowset
```

Take a look here for more info: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe RageZ is right in that you can't have a single model that spans multiple tables without using some sort of ORM.

However, you can easily enough have User_Row->getNewsArticles() and News_Row->getUser() methods.